# Fix menu-bar at top of page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I tried fixing menu-bar at top of page and without the search-box and social icons, however no luck. I worked with navbar-fixed-top in my highest nested element but it doesnt seem to work.

Here my BOOTPLY... [BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/ue213glNO0)

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.menu-container {
    background-color:red;
    min-height:20px;
 position:relative
}

.navbar-nav a:hover {
    color:#000
}

.navbar-nav a:link {
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:'century schoolbook';
    color:#000;
 text-decoration:overline
}

.brand-name a {
 text-decoration:none
}

.brand-name img {
 max-width:137px;
 padding:2px;
 /*position:absolute;*/
 left:0px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}

.navbar-form input,.form-inline input {
    width:auto
}

#nav.affix {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:10
}

#sidebar.affix-top {
    position:static
}

#sidebar.affix {
    position:fixed;
    top:80px
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color:#000;
    font-family:'LuzSans-Book';
    font-size:14px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    background-color:#A10000;
    color:#000
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    background-color:#000;
}

.navbar-custom-social {
    height:15px;
    float:right;
    clear:none;
    margin-right:25px
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
 padding-top:0
}

.search p {
    background-color:blue;
    border:4px dotted black;
    width:20%
  }
  
.social p {
      background-color:orange;
    border:4px dotted green;
  width:20%
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header id="nav navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
                      
                        <div class="clearfix menu-container">
                            <div class="pull-right clearfix toggle_btn_wrap">
                                <a class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pull-left brand-name">
                                <a href="#"><img alt="BRANDNAME" src=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix prevent-float"></div>
                          <div class="item">item-1</div>
                          <div class="item">item-2</div>
                          <div class="item">item-3</div>
                          
                            </div>
        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix search_and_social">
                            <div class="search">
                              <p>SEARCH BOX</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="social">
                              <p>SOCIAL-ICONS</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
            </header>
<div class="content">CONTENT</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT2</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT3</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT4</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT5</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT6</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT2</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT3</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT4</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT5</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT6</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT2</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT3</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT4</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT5</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT6</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header id="nav navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

                        <div class="clearfix menu-container">
                            <div class="pull-right clearfix toggle_btn_wrap">
                                <a class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pull-left brand-name">
                                <a href="#"><img alt="BRANDNAME" src=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix prevent-float"></div>
                          <div class="item">item-1</div>
                          <div class="item">item-2</div>
                          <div class="item">item-3</div>

                            </div>
                             </div>
                        <div class="clearfix search_and_social">
                            <div class="search">
                              <p>SEARCH BOX</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="social">
                              <p>SOCIAL-ICONS</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </header>
<div class="content">CONTENT</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT2</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT3</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT4</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT5</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT6</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT2</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT3</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT4</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT5</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT6</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT2</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT3</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT4</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT5</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT6</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your header tag has it's classes as an id.

```
<header id="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
```

Should be

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
```

You may find adding navbar-default to it displays it better.

```
<header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

See http://www.bootply.com/JevhIDvg5G